# Change the appearance of puppet VM while taking ssh connection

Tags: puppet, putty

[image]I just downloaded puppet VM . when I poweron this and took ssh session, the screen looks different. Anyone has any idea, how to make it full screen? pic in attached.

Comment: this for me is more like a putty environment setting issue, which you need check by yourself.

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.